# Show/Hide Variant Metafield Data on Product Page in Shopify

Tags: shopify, variant

I am trying to show data for a specific variant metafield on a product page in shopify. If a variant is selected I would like to show the div with the corresponding id. I have searched all over the internet and cannot find a solution that works. Any help would be appreciated.

options created by shopify:

```
    <select id="product-selectors" name="id" style="display:none">                    
                <option selected="selected" value="7991232067">Black / Small</option>
                <option value="7991232515">Black / Medium</option>                    
                <option value="7991232387">Black / Large</option>                    
                <option value="7991232323">Black / Extra Large</option>                    
                <option value="7991232259">Orange / Small</option>                    
                <option value="7991232451">Orange / Medium</option>                    
                <option value="7991232131">Orange / Large</option>                    
                <option value="7991232195">Orange / Extra Large</option>                    
              </select>
```

this:

```
    {% for variant in product.variants %}               
    <div class="variant-weight" id="{{variant.id}}"><label>Estimated Weight:</label><span class="estimated-weight"> {% if variant.metafields.bikebuilder.weight %}{{ variant.metafields.bikebuilder.weight }}{% else %}n/a{% endif %}</span></div>
    {% endfor %}
```

creates these divs, one for each variant:

```
    <div class="variant-weight" id="7991232067"><label>Estimated Weight:</label><span class="estimated-weight"> 25898</span></div>
    <div class="variant-weight" id="7991232515"><label>Estimated Weight:</label><span class="estimated-weight"> n/a</span></div>
    <div class="variant-weight" id="7991232387"><label>Estimated Weight:</label><span class="estimated-weight"> 25898</span></div>
    <div class="variant-weight" id="7991232323"><label>Estimated Weight:</label><span class="estimated-weight"> 25898</span></div>
    <div class="variant-weight" id="7991232259"><label>Estimated Weight:</label><span class="estimated-weight"> 25898</span></div>
    <div class="variant-weight" id="7991232451"><label>Estimated Weight:</label><span class="estimated-weight"> 25898</span></div>
    <div class="variant-weight" id="7991232131"><label>Estimated Weight:</label><span class="estimated-weight"> 25898</span></div>
    <div class="variant-weight" id="7991232195"><label>Estimated Weight:</label><span class="estimated-weight"> 2948</span></div>
```

and the code that does not work:

```
    if (variant) {
    $('select[name="id"]').change(function() {
    var targetId = $(variant).find('select[name="id"] option:selected').val();
    $('#' + targetId).show();
    });
    }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93td18kt/)

Comment: `if (variant)` is not defined ...

Answer (score 1):

turns out there is a hidden input that controls the variations. this works:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var value = $('select[name=id]').val();
    var targetId = '#'+$('select[name=id]').val();
    $(targetId).show();
});
    $('.swatch input').on('change', function(){
var value = $('select[name=id]').val();
    var targetId = '#'+$('select[name=id]').val();
    $(targetId).show();
    $(targetId).hide();
    });
```

Comment: turns out this code only works for products with 2 or more variants. for any product that has no variation, the "targetId" does not display

Answer (score 0):

This work:

```
var variant = true;
if (variant) {
  $('select[name="id"]').change(function() {
      var targetId = $(this).find(' option:selected').val();
      $('.variant-weight').hide();
      $('#' + targetId).show();
  });
}
```

[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/tk3sLuu5/)